# dotnet new ... create template structure for whole solution not just api

Tags: c#, .net

My solution folder structure is

```
 - MyAwesomeProject.Api
 - MyAwesomeProject.Domain
 - MyAwesomeProject.Persistance
   MyAwesomeProject.sln
   README.md
```

I want to create one template for many project using the power of dotnet new -n...
I add template.json

```
{
  "$schema": "http://json.schemastore.org/template",
  "description": "Custom web API template",
  "classifications": [ "Web" ],
  "identity": "Template.WebApi",
  "name": "MyAwesomeProject- Template ASP.NET Core Web Api",
  "shortName": "my-template",
  "tags": {
    "language": "C#",
    "type": "project"
  },
  "preferNameDirectory": true
}
```

now in the cli when I hit

```
dotnet new my-template MyAwesomeProject -n MyCoolProject
```

the MyCoolProject gets created successfully with all the folder structure inside MyAwesomeProject.Api project.

My question is:
how can i expand this in order to create whole solution folder structure (with domain, and persistance) not just api project?

Comment: Seems like it is possible, guide here: https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/how-create-custom-multi-project-net-template-visual-studio-gayle/